# How to hide tag or category name from showing on featured image?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm using custom blogger template and I want to hide the text(tags) which display on the featured images of the post on homepage.please suggest me the html code to hide that text.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is to found with a right click on tags of the featured image and select "inspect element" on chrome, to find the class of the tags and after that to give on this specific class the CSS code `"display:none"`....